# How to efficiently pre-fetch posts in a feed that are being replied to by other posts

Tags: mongodb, rest, database-design, architecture, feed

*Problem is frontend/backend-agnostic, but technically I'm doing this in Flutter, Rust, and MongoDB.*

**I'm trying to design a feed of posts, where posts can either be:**

- Standalone posts.
- Posts that "reply" to another post, or have a post as their "child". This is similar to Twitter's Quoted Tweets.

Example:

[image]

Posts can have *infinite* number of children (only one per post though). For example, this means post W could have a child of post X, which could have a child of post Y, which could have a child of post Z, etc. They can also have no children.

**The problem is that I'm not sure how/when to load/preload these children posts in.**

## This is my current idea of how to implement this

Load all parent posts in first (from the example picture, this would be #1, #2 and #3), then after that, call a function to load in all the children of posts, if they exist. This is when post #4 would then be loaded (2 total calls if a post has a child; 1 if no child).

This is what post #3 would look like initially.

```
{
    "post_data": {...},
    "child_id": "vn79502v367b8"
}
```

The code would display the initial post with a loading indicator for its child, then since it would see `child_id` is not null, it would call the backend to give it that child post data, upon receiving it, it would populate it on the page.

If that child has no child of its own, it would look like this:

```
{
    "post_data": {...},
    "child_id": null
}
```

This would then be the end. **However**, if the child has its own child, the response would look like this again:

```
{
    "post_data": {...},
    "child_id": "v38phnv642c17n8",
}
```

This essentially just repeats again and again, loading the child after the parent is initially loaded. Sort of staying half a step ahead of the user.

#### Is this the best way to design this system? Thanks so much for feedback!